# how make adaptive blank spaces in android

Tags: android-constraintlayout

How can I implement this action via constraintLayout?

When keyboard opens blank space collapsed and vice versa.

[image: instagram login page]

## UPDATE

because stackoverflow blocked me for sending answer, I had to send here :(

SOLUTION:

I found my answer in using chainStyle for constraint layout:
with this feature all space areas made adaptive.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/z_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Language"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/insta"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/title_set_passcode"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/z_img" />


<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/title_set_passcode"
    style="@style/LightText.LargeText.Bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:text="Login form"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/il_login_passcode"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />
```

[image: in design]
[image: result]